# Metropolis - Hastings sampling: histogram shapes looks sane but bin values are off

Tags: self-study, bayesian, markov-chain-montecarlo, lognormal-distribution, metropolis-hastings

The target distribution is of the form:

$ p(x) = x^{-6}.e^{\frac{-2.475}{x}}$ with a support in the interval $[0.0, 2.0]$.

This gives a plot like

[image: plot target over [0.0, 2.0]]

Now, to choose a proposal kernel, I think a lognormal may suffice. To determine what the values of the hyperparameters for the lognormal is that could be a best fit to the target distribution, I played around and identify *s = 0.5*, *loc = 0*, *scale = 0.5* and a *constant = 0.30* that multiples the proposal kernel so that it looks like the target distribution.

So my proposal kernel has the form
$q(.|.)$ = `0.3 * lognorm.pdf(x, s, loc, scale)` using the package
https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.lognorm.html

Comparing the target distribution with the introduced proposal kernel $q(.|.) $ (this proposal kernel will now be used for the Metropolis - Hastings sampling):

[image]

Here is how I implement the M-H algorithm:

1. First I initialise a value for x (call this $x_{0}$)
2. I specify a markov chain length $t \in [1, T]$
3. Then I condition the proposal kernel $q(.|.)$ on $x_{0}$ to sample an updated value for $x$: this is $x^{t} \sim q(x^{t} | x_{0})$.
   This is reflected at the algorithmic level by replacing the *loc* parameter in $q(.|.)$ with $x_{0}$
4. Next, sample $x_{t-1}$ from $q(x^{t-1} | x_{t})$. Algorithmically, this is replacing the *loc* parameter in $q(.|.)$ with $x_{t}$
5. 3., 4. allows me to compute the Hastings ratio $H$ for $x$: this is just $x_{t-1}/x{t}$
6. the target distribution $p$ of $x_{t}$ and $p$ of $x_{t-1}$ respectively: $p(x_{t}), p(x_{t-1})$
7. the target distribution ratio $T$: $p(x_{t})/p(x_{t-1})$
8. compute the M-H ratio $r$: $r = T * H$
9. randomly sample $u$ from a uniform distribution on the support $(0,1)$
10. if $u >= r$ then accept $x_{t}$  else reject.
11. The next iteration for $t$ begins: this time $x_{t}$ is used as an initial value in 3.

After 1000 t's the plot below emerge:

[image]

`matplotlib.pyplot.hist(accepted_x_samples, density = False, weights = weights)`

As you can see the shape looks *OK* but the bin axis is off. The vertical axis is also suspect.

Been working on this for days diligently but I cannot figure this out. Please, any help is appreciated.

Comment: The target is a truncated inverse Gamma distribution that can be simulated on its own.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you have some confusions in your code and description of the algorithm. I suggest you look at wikipedia and learn the terminology therein. (e.g. "acceptance ratio", not using the Hastings ratios)

Some problems with your code/attempt/proposed solution:

- The proposal will only give values to the right of the current position.
- Having a proposal that is 'close' to the target distribution is sensible in rejection sampling, but not in MC-sampling like metropolis hastings. I think you are mixing the two concepts.
- Step 5 computes a ratio of points, not of probabilities
- The histogram is not normalized, but also use some sample weights which you never explained what they were. It also plots ``accepted'' points, not all points. You are not clear about the distinction. You should plot accepted proposals and all the duplications due to rejection.
- The target distribution has finite support that you do not enforce. It is also not normalized (may be a problem, may not be)

I have attached a simple MH implementation. Noteworhy things:

- Does not account for burn-in - there will be some transient in the beginning.
- The step length is not tuned - I don't know if it rejects too much or not. It may be inefficient.
- The proposal kernel (gaussian) is symmetric, so the acceptance ratio can be simplified. I kept it in the full form to make it simpler to extend the code.

I suggest you take a starter code (like mine, or from somewhere else on the internet) and change some piece here, instead of implementing it from scratch the first time. MCMC is always tricky to debug, and having a working prototype to play with helps.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy.integrate
np.random.seed(0)

# define the target density
def p_pdf_unnormalized(x):
    return np.exp(-2.475/x)/x**6 if 0<x<=2 else 0

# The proposal kernel used here is a gaussian, not lognormal
sigma2 = 0.3**2
g_log_pdf = lambda x,x_proposal: -(x-x_proposal)**2/2/sigma2 - 0.5*np.log(2*np.pi*sigma2)
g_sample = lambda x1: np.random.standard_normal()*np.sqrt(sigma2) + x1

def A(x,x_proposal):
    """Two problems must be dealt with to avoid numerical errors:
    - use log-probabilities
    - if the proposal has target density 0, just discard it
    """
    return 0 if p_pdf_unnormalized(x_proposal) == 0 else  min(
            1,
            np.exp(
                np.log(p_pdf_unnormalized(x_proposal))
                -np.log(p_pdf_unnormalized(x))
                +g_log_pdf(x,x_proposal)
                -g_log_pdf(x_proposal,x))
            )

#
# Run metropolis hastings
#
T = 2000
x = np.zeros(T)
x[0] = 1
for t in range(T-1):
    x_proposed = g_sample(x[t])
    acceptance_probability = A(x[t],x_proposed)
    if np.random.uniform() <= acceptance_probability:
        x[t+1] = x_proposed
    else:
        x[t+1] = x[t]


#
# Plot results
#
plt.hist(x, density = True)
p_normalization,_ = scipy.integrate.quad(p_pdf_unnormalized,0,2)
p_pdf = lambda x: p_pdf_unnormalized(x)/p_normalization
plt.plot(a:=np.linspace(0,2,100),[p_pdf(aa) for aa in a])
plt.show()
```

[image: output of the attached code]

Comment: Thank you for taking the effort to address my doubts and point out my misguidance.

If you do not mind:

"The proposal will only give values to the right of the current position.": why would this be the case? How can I best gain an intuition of this?

"Having a proposal that is 'close' to the target distribution is sensible in rejection sampling, but not in MC-sampling like metropolis hastings. I think you are mixing the two concepts." - It is possible that I am confused. However, in a text I read it mention a good proposal is one close to the target. What is a good proposal then?

Comment: Regarding good proposals: make a separate question for that. It is a subject in itself.

Comment: Regarding proposals only being to the right: the location parameter in `sklearn` is 0 for the lognormal, and the distribution has support on the nonnegatives. It can only give values lareger than `loc`. So if `loc`$=x_t$, then proposals will be larger than that.

Comment: On your third point: I made a typo but my computation was of computing the ratio of probabilities base on the appropriate conditionals.

Comment: 2 questions: 
1. g_sample is defined as a standard normal multiplied by signma2 before adding a term x1 - what motivates this?
2. also, what motivates sigma2 = $0.3 ^{2}$?

Comment: A gaussian is simple to sample and have intuition about. For a unimodal distribution like this, it should be good enough. My hope is that 0.3 will give a good acceptance rate. However, you have to check if that is the case. See wikipedia for details. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metropolis%E2%80%93Hastings_algorithm